# WordPress Toolset Template Showing Blank Page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins, custom-post-type

I have an Issues CPT created using Toolset on wordpress. Single issues are currently being displayed fine using the file single.php.

[image]

Client wants a new template for issues, so I created a new file single-issues.php.

Toolset finds this file, and updates it on the admin end to show that Issues should show using single-issues.php
[image]

When I look at single issues now, the page is completely blank with no console errors.
[image]

This happens regardless of what I put inside the single-issues.php, if only echo hello, or even if i just copy/paste exactly what is in single.php into it.

If i remove the single-issues.php file, and let it go back to single.php, it displays fine again.

Why is Toolset displaying files other than single.php as a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was Wrong file permissions. If you are getting blank pages see if you have something with this text in your debug log

`failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...`

And then use ftp to update your permissions on the corresponding file rwxrwxr-x